# What do I do when my second order CFA model is not identified?

Tags: psychometrics, confirmatory-factor, identifiability

I am assessing a measurement model of a three-factor organisational commitment scale for my PhD project. Although congeneric single factor and first order CFA models have produced excellent model fit indices, second-order CFA integrating the three factors (affective commitment, normative commitment and continuance commitment) in one model shows that the model is unidentified. what can I do for my model to be identified?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could share the fit indices that have been estimated, and the software used.  Is your second order model based on sound theory?